# Constructing Green's function for 2D

Tags: partial-differential-equations, greens-function

Consider the Green’s function problem in the domain $D=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R} \times[0,a]\}$ i.e $-\infty<x<\infty, 0\leq y \leq a$
where $a > 0$: $$\Delta G(x,y|s,t)=\delta(x-s)\delta(y-t)\ \ in \ \ D$$
$$G(x,y|s,t)=0\ \ at \ y=0,y=a$$

I want to construct a Green’s function solution to this problem using images.

$\mathbf{My\ attempt}:$

Let $G= f+g$ where $f$ is the free space Green's ,i.e,  $f=\frac{1}{2\pi} \ln \sqrt {(x-s)^2+(y-t)^2}$ where $(s,t) \in D$, and $g$ being any harmonic function such that $g=-f$ at $y=0,y=a$. I tried the function $g=-\frac{1}{2\pi}\ln \sqrt{(x-s)^2+(y+t)^2-4yt}$ which clearly satisfies $f=-g$ at $y=0,y=a$ but $g$ is not harmonic in D.

I would appreciate any help or hint about that.

Comment: The method of images is a pretty good hint! Try reflecting the charge at $(s,t)$ across the lines y=a and y=0 (with opposite sign to ground these lines).

Comment: That is actully what I am willing to  do, so as I stated in my solution I am still unable to find the image point for that could you help me more.

Comment: Where are you getting stuck? Do you understand what i mean by reflecting the charge across those lines?

Comment: I do not clearly, did you mean (0,-a)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: The function
$$
 G(x,y\vert s,t)=\frac1{2\pi}\ln\sqrt{(x-s)^2+(y-t)^2}-
\frac1{2\pi}\ln\sqrt{(x-s)^2+(y-(2a-t))^2}
$$
Satisfies $\Delta  G=\delta(x-s)\delta(y-t)$ and $ G(x,a\vert s,t)=0$. Can you add another function to ensure it vanishes on $y=0$, using the same sort of technique?

The idea of the above physically is to place an oppositely charged particle on the other side of the line $y=a$ to ensure $ G=0$ on $y=a$ (this new function is harmonic for $0\leq y\leq a$ because the Green's function is away from the point of singularity). To complete the problem, you do the same thing to ensure $ G=0$.

Comment: I agree but did you mean $$
 G(x,y\vert s,t)=\frac1{2\pi}\ln\sqrt{(x-s)^2+(y-t)^2}-
\frac1{2\pi}\ln\sqrt{(x-s)^2+(y-(2a-t))^2}+(\frac1{2\pi}\ln\sqrt{(x-s)^2+(y-t)^2}-\frac1{2\pi}\ln\sqrt{(x-s)^2+(y+t)^2})
$$

Comment: @Ahmed I realized my hint doesn't get you all that close to the answer. Note that your function doesn't vanish at each line in the boundary. You need an infinite sequence of charges.

Comment: What do you mean by charges? image points?

Comment: yes, image points

Comment: Could you provide further hint with that, I am getting a little be confused?